# Docker error process_linux.go:319: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused "EOF": unknown

Tags: node.js, docker

My Docker container will not start. The error message in the log is:

```
{"message":"OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused \
"process_linux.go:319: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused \\\"EOF\\\"\": unknown"}
```

What is next step?

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by setting:

```
sysctl -w user.max_user_namespaces=15000
```

Comment: This solved my issue, but it would be great to have an explanation for what this does, and why it fixes this issue.

Answer (score 2):

When using kubernetes, this error can be caused by a wrong memory notation in `deployment` settings.

Wrong

```
...
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      container:
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "300m"
          requests:
            memory: "300m"
```

Fixed:

```
...
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      container:
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "300Mi"
          requests:
            memory: "300Mi"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update 2021:

New answers in the below-linked thread assert that they have found solutions. [See this answer](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/40835#issuecomment-730981130-permalink), for example.

#### Original Answer:

This is a known feature.[{1}](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/40835)

The solution that worked for me was to **restart the server** instance.

In Plesk:

1. Tools & Settings (from side menu)
2. Server Management (2nd grouping on left side)
3. click on **Restart Server**

#### Reference:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/40835

Answer (score 0):

For CentOS users, setting `max_user_namespaces` can be done as follows.
`echo 15000 > /proc/sys/user/max_user_namespaces`
https://superuser.com/a/1294246/1640737

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by upgrade the linux kernel from `4.15.0-202-generic` to `4.15.0-206-generic #217-Ubuntu`.

My `docker --version` is **20.10.17, build 100c701**.

- 1, install the newest kernel: `sudo apt-get install -y linux-image-generic`
- 2, reboot the server

Tips: **check your environment will be suitable for the newest kernel before install it** !